# Disable index build on certain fields

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

How do I disable indexes on specific fields in elasticsearch, currently by default all the fields are being indexed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Logstash:

Nearly all filters have a `remove_field` configuration that you can remove a field from your event. If you use a filter you can check documentation and add it if exist or you can use mutate][1](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-mutate.html#plugins-filters-mutate-remove_field) filter as:

```
filter {
  mutate {
    remove_field => [ "foo_%{somefield}", "my_extraneous_field" ]
  }
}
```

Elasticsearch:

If you want the field to be not indexed you can set `index` property of the field to as `no` on mapping.

```
{
    "field_name": {
        "type": "string",
        "index": "no"
    }
}
```

Possible values:

> - analyzed
>
>   First analyze the string and then index it. In other words, index this field as full text.
> - not_analyzed
>
>   Index this field, so it is searchable, but index the value exactly as specified. Do not analyze it.
> - no
>
>   Don’t index this field at all. This field will not be searchable.

Comment: I need the field as part of the event. However I don't want to index it in elasticsearch

Comment: Updated my answer.

Comment: Is it possible to configure in elastic search saying, i don't want fields x,y,z never to be indexed...before the indexes are built...the above mapping update should be run once the indexes are built right?

Comment: You can use index templates: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-templates.html

Comment: Thanks !! Managed to get it working using index templates